# Combining Content Data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When I first start one of my Wordpress blogs, I had the permanent URL for each post include the date of posting.

The slug format looked like this: 
/blog/2010/01/25/this-is-my-article/

Later on, I changed it so that the date was not included in the permanent URL, like this:
/blog/this-is-my-article/ and setup a redirect plugin to make sure that users would get to the page they wanted until the site was re-indexed.

In Google Analytics, when I review the stats for content I now have multiple records for what is essentially the same page. ie:

Top Content List:

1. 45 Pageviews- /blog/this-is-my-article/
2. 24 Pageviews- /blog/2010/01/25/this-is-my-article/
3. 33 Pageviews- /blog/some-other-article/

Is there any way to combine those records somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to do this is by using Filters, "**Advanced Filters**" in particular. In your case, you'll use one Filter for each blog-article pair (one URL w/ title + date, the other URL w/ title only)--this way, you'll merge the two URLs into a single line item in your reports.

(I'm assuming you haven't done this before, so,

1. from the "Settings" Page in GA,
   click on "Filter Manager" (probably
   bottom right)
2. Click "Add Filter"
3. Enter a name for this Filter
   (article name is probably a good
   choice)
4. Click the radio-button below that
   textbox, "Custom Filter"
5. Then Click the last of a set of six
   radio buttons below that, "Advanced"
6. for "Field -> A -> Extract A" select
   "Request URI" from the dropdown menu
7. Beside that menu is a textbox, type
   in the article title
   (this-is-my-article)--no parens, no
   quotes
8. The next line ("Field B -> ....")
   leave blank
9. The line after that, which begins
   with "Output To->" select "Request
   URI" from the dropdown
10. Type in the article title (with "/"
     at the beginning, no space; and
     ".html" at the end, no space)
11. Click "Yes" for "Field A Required"
12. Click "No" for "Field B Required"
13. Click "Yes" for Override Output
     Field
14. Click "No" for "Case Sensitive"
15. Below that, you'll select which of
     your Website Profiles you want to
     apply this Filter to
16. Click "save changes" and you're
     done (obviously you'll need to
     repeat this process for each URL
     pair).

Comment: Doug, thank you this was a great tutorial. However - will this filter retroactively change the URLs in my top content list? For my first attempt, after I made the filter, the pageviews results for the two twin content pieces were still separate, with one having he date slug in it.

Is this retroactive, or does it only work on new incoming data?

Comment: David, Filters are *not* retroactive--that's the case for nearly all GA functions, so i treat it as a background assumption. Still, i should have made it explicit in my answer. I just double-checked this by the way to confirm (see my diigo annotated page here, http://diigo.com/0a01o).

Comment: @doug, is there a way to do this so that you do not need to repeat the process for every URL pair? I have thousands of URLs that should be combined, and doing so manually wouldn't make sense. Perhaps some type of regex? My question is listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576951/combining-similar-urls-in-google-analytics).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an "[Advanced Segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033017?hl=en)", then easily use that in your reporting.