# Combining similar URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have various articles that come in different format types (ex: pdf, html). I'd like to create a filter in my Google Analytics account that will simply take off file types at the end of the article URLs and then combine the same article URLs together, so that I would be able to view the total pageviews for that article from all of its forms. For example, I have several articles, and they may be listed like so:

/site/42/5/1234.html

/site/28/12/5555.pdf

/site/42/5/1234

/site/42/5/1234.pdf

/site/28/12/5555

What I would like to do is combine the pageviews for all of the same articles -- so in this example, the pageviews would be combined into just two URLs: (site/42/5/1234 and /site/28/12/5555.

How would you suggest creating a filter that would do such a task?

Answer (score 1):

**first I would recommend keeping at least one profile where you keep this information** separately; you'll want to know what format people are consuming the articles in so you know what kind of content to create.

Next, you need to create an advanced profile filter. [Here's](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en) the Google article about them.

And [here's](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/sr8yGN4Zlqs) a GPF thread about the same question.

To tailor it to your needs, your first field might look something more like this:

```
(\/site\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]+)($)?|\.html|.\pdf
```

...Depending on the number of numbers in each folder (I have it set up to accept 1 or 2 numbers like how you have it written). The end part `($)?|\.html|.\pdf` says, "**match nothing at the end, OR .html OR .pdf**"; you could change the specific file extensions to `.*` to match all file types.

Then just use `$A1` as in the example provided for the output; this signifies that you want to use only what's in the first set of round brackets in field A

Sometimes it takes some playing with but it's pretty powerful :)

Real time reports can be your friend to catch what's coming in without having to wait a day to see if it's working.