# How to combine Google Analytics events with similar labels

Tags: google-analytics

We have a custom event tracking script running on our site that ends up saving any `href` value from any `<a>` link as an event label when clicked on.

So if we have

```
<a href="/news/resources/information.pdf">click</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/news/resources/information.pdf">click</a>
```

it creates 2 different events with those respective labels, even though they actually go to the same file.

Is there a way - either through custom reports or otherwise - to combine these events so that it categorizes anything that starts with `http://www.website.com/` and `/` to be the same event?  Or is this something I'd need to update on the webpage itself when it sends the event?

EDIT: or do I have to do something like [Combining similar URLs in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576951/combining-similar-urls-in-google-analytics) by creating a new view with a filter on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a custom filter that does a search and replace of your URLs like this:

```
Search: http://www\.website\.com
Replace: <leave blank>
```

So that will look for all occurrences of "http://www.website.com" and replace it with a blank (effectively removing it from those strings where it occurs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this something that needs to be done on a view when we initially set it up, or can I retroactively reorganize the data this way?  Or is it a custom segment?  Or a custom report?  I understand the concept, just unsure of where to actually do it.

Comment: This would be done at the view level, but it would not be retroactive.