# Combining similar URLs in Google Analytics (with a twist)

Tags: google-analytics

I have a lot of similar URLs that I would like to merge in Google Analytics. I've managed to merge a lot of them already. However I've now run into a bit of a problem.

I have URLs that look something like this;

article/4567/edit
article/87478548/edit

article/82984786/add
article/8374/add

How would I go about merging these URLs so that they display as;

article/edit
article/add

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*: I also need to be able to have GA display every article in one line on the table called "article/" regardless of any ID that is after it. I don't want the table to look like:

article/12342 1,000 views
article/7465890 900 views

I need it to display as:

article/ 1,900 views

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Content Drilldown reports to see the `/article` pages only?

Comment: I have had a look in there but is there any way to display it like that on the "All pages" section? The content drilldown section doesn't ignore all the IDs though. I would like to ignore all the IDs and just have it display "article/" as an overall total.

Comment: Content Groups would also be another way. Did you still want to be able to see the `/article/edit` and `/article/add` breakdowns though? Because I don't think you'd be able to have it all with the breakdowns, and with just the `/article` grouping.

Comment: I've had a look at content grouping. I don't need to see the breakdown at all though. Just want all articles regardless of their ID to appear as "/article". I am getting a warning from GA saying that I have too many URLs (article/ is one example out of quite a few items on the site that have IDs that I need to ignore while still recording a "/edit" or "/add" at the end of it).

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Advanced filter that combines the relevant parts for you:

[image]

The output would be `/article/edit` or `/article/add`, with everything and anything between those removed.

**EDIT**:
If you just want everything, regardless of `/edit`, `/add`, `/12341/edit`, `/7305/add`, `/whatever/edit`, to show up just as `/article`, then you can just change your filter like this:

`Field A`: Request URI = (/article)/.*

`Output to`: Request URI = $A1

This will convert the following examples:

- /article/123/edit -> /article
- /article/2345/add -> /article
- /article/anything -> /article

Comment: I gave this a go yesterday. I put 
"Field A ->Extract A: (/article)/\.*/(edit|add|moreexamples|otherstuff) 
and for the Output I put: 
$A1/$A2/$A3/$A4.
When I checked the analytcis this morning the pages appeared like:
article//edit/$A4/article/ .
Any ideas what happened here?

Comment: The regex of @nyuen is wrong scaped, i fixed it, Also you need to know that you only have 2 extraction $A1 = (\/article) and $A2 = (edit|add|moreexmaples|otherstuff), there is no need to add $A3 or $A4, they dont exist at all.
The way is the good one , but  we need to fix the regex,try with this one:
Field A
\/(article)\/.*\/(edit|add|moreexmaples|otherstuff)
Extraction
\/$A1\/$A2

Comment: Ah I understand now thanks. Why did you put \/ on either side of (article)? What does that do differently?

Comment: The / is a special char, you need to scape it using \ ,more info on: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html

Comment: Note that `/` does NOT need to be escaped because GA uses a different Regex engine. My answer still stays the same. Here is the reference to GA's regex https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en

Comment: @nyuen oh you're totally rigth!, it's not mandatory space the /! sorry about that, i dont noticed. But as my defense,there is no problem to escape it.
http://i.imgur.com/TFHf2Hng.png

Answer (score -1):

From this [Combining similar URLs in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576951/combining-similar-urls-in-google-analytics) you can find out how to do it. You need to use a regex. Something like this should work (did not test it).

```
(article\/)[0-9]*\/(edit|add)
```

Comment: Take care, this answer can be wrongly interpreted, if you add this on the replace and search filter, it replaces the whole string, not just the number part setting all the matches pages as (not set)