# Combining URLs in Google Analytics (advanced)

Tags: google-analytics

I recently posted a question about combining URLs in Google Analytics. It can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122513/combining-similar-urls-in-google-analytics-with-a-twist)

The answer I accepted as correct worked fine. However it's a bit more complicated than I thought. I managed to get GA to change "article/4567/edit" to "article/edit" and so on. The complicated part is that I also would like to get rid of all the article IDs and bundle them all into "article/"

How would I go about doing this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more details? Not sure what you mean by "bundling" them all into "article/". In a way, the filter from the linked answer shows you how to bundle them into "edit" and "add".  I reckon you could extend the filter to bundle them further. It looks like it would just require small tweaks to the adv. filter in the answer, like remove the second set of brackets and remove the `/$A2` part in the output.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Let me try explain. Each article has an ID. Sometimes that ID has "/add" or "/edit" after it. I managed to get GA to ignore IDs and output it like "article/edit" which shows all the views for combined for all the articles that were edited. That's great but I now need to ignore the IDs and get GA to output all the articles that don't have "/add" or "/edit" after under one heading "articles/". Does that make more sense?..

Comment: Can you please provide examples in your original question? I think I understand but wanted to confirm.

Comment: Hi. I've edited my original question that I linked in the above post. Thanks for having a look. Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Content grouping before? It helped me solve a similar problem:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en