# Removing IDs from links in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

[I have followed the thread here about splitting out similar URLs, and follwed the example given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122513/combining-similar-urls-in-google-analytics-with-a-twist) but I have a bit of a problem.

Some of the URLs in my analytics page are being sorted correctly, then some of them don't seem to get sorted at all. In the 2nd image you can see the problem I'm having. The 4th and 5th links on that image, are meant to be grouped under the 1st link of /blog/

I've included a screenshot of my filter as well, as I might be missing something in the filter, to group all the /blog/ links together.

The way the links are in the website is like this:

great-blogs.co.uk/blog/123456789012345

Any idea on how to go about combining these rouge links into the main /blog/ link would be great.

[image: Filter settings]

[image: Image of Analytics]

Comment: Hi, I think the answer you linked to has the solution, in the section marked as "EDIT". Your field A would be `(/blog/).*` and the output field would be `$A1`. So everything will be combined to just `/blog/`.

Comment: Hi nyuen, won't that get rid of the /blog/edit and the /blog/new ?

Comment: Yes it will. Sorry i thought you wanted everything merged into just `/blog/`. So it should be `/blog/`, `/blog/edit`, or `/blog/add` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*)/\d+(.*)
```

That works perfectly with the problem I had with the IDs, buried in the middle of the urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pages grouped only into `/blog/`, `/blog/edit`, or `/blog/new` then you would need field A of your filter to be

```
(/blog/)[0-9]+$|/blog/.*/(edit|new)
```

This assumes that the string that could show up at the end is numbers only, eg. `/blog/1478744474`. You could also modify this so that if you know it's just going to be numbers before `/edit` or `/new`, then the regex could be

```
(/blog/)[0-9]+$|/blog/[0-9]*/(edit|new)
```

The output field would be `$A1$A2`. Notice how I included the slashes in the field A groupings to make the output look a little cleaner.

Test this though, because I'm on a mobile right now and can't access a good online regex tester!!!

**EDIT**:

Two changes: 1) note how the `*` is now a `+` so that the number is actually required (eg. `/blog/1234`). 2) I had to modify the regex because I finally got to testing it and found that the brackets might impact the matching, and also because the advanced filters use the same brackets to piece together the output, I had to redo the regex and break it up into two matching groups (that probably doesn't make sense but I hope it works!).

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. I've added it to my analytics. In the 2nd link is the   |[0-9]./ part right, is the dot in the right space?

Comment: Yikes, they should be stars not dots! Sorry! Good catch!

Comment: I added the bottom option, '(/blog/)[0-9]+$|/blog/[0-9]*/(edit|new)' to my analytics and its giving me 2 outputs now, one is '//blog/' and the other is '/blog//' Any idea how to get it go give /blog/edit ?

Comment: Can you please post what your filter looks like? Probably an easy fix with the brackets.

Comment: OK, it looks a little different than what I had. Just remember that for advanced filters, the brackets matter! Each set of brackets, `(...)`, corresponds to a grouping, so the first set of brackets would correspond to `$A1` and the second set to `$A2`. Your filter shows three sets of brackets, and your output also shows a `/` between the groupings. So might have to play around with all those to make it all work. Remember to test it out in a TEST view first (if not already)!